# Bootstrap accordion header with column issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

I have a problem with accordion. I use bootstrap accordion but ı need to add column in the accordion head panel div. So when I added columns accordion does not work very well.

See the kod full screen please. You can see accordion height issue. Accordion height acting like crazy when I use the columns in the accordion header.

Any help would be good. Thank you.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="myaccount-top-head" class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
  <div class="col-sm-12 bg">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="orderstitles">
      <div class="col-sm-2"><strong>Tarih</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"><strong>Sipariş Numarası</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"><strong>Tutar</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"><strong>Kanal</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"><strong>Sipariş Durumu</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseOne">
          <div class="col-sm-2"><strong>Tarih</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3"><strong>Sipariş Numarası</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2"><strong>Tutar</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2"><strong>Kanal</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2"><strong>Sipariş Durumu</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">ASDADASD</div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua
            put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer
            farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Btw, I fixed my problem.

It's work good now.

```css
.panel-heading {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="myaccount-top-head" class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
  <div class="col-sm-12 bg">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="orderstitles">
      <div class="col-sm-2"><strong>Tarih</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"><strong>Sipariş Numarası</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"><strong>Tutar</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"><strong>Kanal</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"><strong>Sipariş Durumu</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseOne">
          <div class="col-sm-2"><strong>Tarih</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3"><strong>Sipariş Numarası</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2"><strong>Tutar</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2"><strong>Kanal</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2"><strong>Sipariş Durumu</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">ASDADASD</div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua
            put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer
            farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```